# jQuery 1.7.2 AJAX call throwing NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, jquery-1.7

I have an issue with jQuery 1.7.2 and the `ajax` function, in that when I call the code below I get the following error in Firefox Firebug console:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments
>   [nsIDOMLocation.replace]

```
    var weights= new Object();

    // weight is then manipulated in here

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/admin/countries/index.php',
            data: ({action: 'sort', cid: cid, weights: weights}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){                    
                alert('suck-sess');
                                    // do stuff in here
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    )
```

I'm not even certain that it's successfuly making the request as when I dump out `$_REQUEST["action"]` in my `index.php` PHP it comes through blank, when it should clearly be 'sort'.

When I execute the code I don't get the success or error alert, so I can't see where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that weights was the problem, as you can see it was defined as a JavaScript object, however I had to use `JSON.stringify(weights)` to pass it through as a JSON-encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMLocation.replace]
```

This is the kind of internal errors thrown by gecko based browsers (firefox). I don't think it's related to your code. Seems to me more like a browser bug.

Comment: I was concerned it was an issue with the version of jQuery I am now using (1.7.2) and the implementation of the `ajax` function, which has since been changed in later versions of jQuery.

Comment: @crmpicco "When the code seems ok, you should check the data". Are you sure `weights` is a valid object. Have a look at [this discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/5442/2011/11/29/16-17) and see if it helps.

Comment: It turned out that `weights` was the problem, as you can see it was defined as a JavaScript object, however I had to use `JSON.stringify(weights)` to pass it through as a JSON-encoded string.

Comment: @crmpicco Glad it worked :). The problem isn't always were it seems to be.